# How to replace informations in a dataFrame using Pandas and Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I need some help:

How could I update the column of the file *file_csv_reference.csv* dataFrame using Pandas and Python?

**file_csv_reference.csv**:

```py
cod_example
123456
123456
123456
789101
789101
121314
121314
```

there are lines with repeated information, I would like to replace all of them with the respective updated code in the file bellow:

**file_with_updated_cod.csv**

```py
old_cod   updated_cod
123456      ;1234567
789101      ;7891011
121314      ;1213141
```

Until now I'm thinking throught this way (but I can't do it run right):

```
import pandas as pd
file01 = pd.read_csv("file_csv_reference.csv", encoding = "utf-8", delimiter = ";", header = 0)
file02 = pd.read_csv("file_with_updated_cod.csv", encoding = "utf-8", delimiter = ";", header = 0)
for oldcod in file01['cod_example']:
    for cod in file02['old_cod']:
       if oldcod == cod:
       #in this part I would like to replace the data in the file01 column cod_example
       # with file01['updated_cod'] in the respective column
```

Could you help me please to solve this situation? Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map`:

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv("file_csv_reference.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("file_with_updated_cod.csv", sep=";")

df1["cod_example"] = df1["cod_example"].map(
    df2.set_index("old_cod")["updated_cod"]
)
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
   cod_example
0      1234567
1      1234567
2      1234567
3      7891011
4      7891011
5      1213141
6      1213141
```